# How to change scale of subplots in Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, subplot

I'm creating a figure with two heat maps

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(20, 15))
heatmap(data1, cmap=color_palette('Greys_r'), square=True, ax=axs[0])
heatmap(data2, cmap=color_palette('Greys_r'), square=True, ax=axs[1])
fig.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

However, the resulting heatmaps are too small (or, the legends are too large)

[image: heatmaps.png]

I've tried [setting `figsize` to `(20, 15)`](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/17540), but it doesn't have any obvious effect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an ugly hack where you have to manipulate the `shrink` parameter manually but can be used for the current problem.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 12)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 12)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(20, 15))
sns.heatmap(data1, cmap=sns.color_palette('Greys_r'), square=True, cbar_kws={"shrink": .42}, ax=axs[0])
sns.heatmap(data2, cmap=sns.color_palette('Greys_r'), square=True, cbar_kws={"shrink": .42}, ax=axs[1])
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: You had a better answer :)  +1

Comment: What's the logic behind the number 0.42?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer this is an ugly hack where the number 0.42 is manipulated visually to have the same height as the plot